# How can I open an Angular Material menu from a controller function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-services, angular-controller

I'm doing a check for a user state and would like to enable and disable a [menu](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/menu) accordingly.

In the markup:

```
<a ... ng-click="ctrl.userMenu($event)"></a>
```

And in the controller:

```
ctrl.userMenu = function (e) {
    if (ctrl.user.has.something) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    } else {
        ctrl.openMenu($mdOpenMenu, e);
    }
};
```

However, this doesn't trigger the menu if the else case is true. I suspect a scope issue. I've also tried wrapping the menu service call in an anonymous function. The menu opens as expected if the call is made directly from the `ng-click` directive. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: could you provide a fiddle/plunker ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was forgetting to pass the menu service along with the `ng-click` directive:

```
<a ... ng-click="ctrl.userMenu($mdOpenMenu, $event)"></a>
// ---------------------------------^

ctrl.userMenu = function (m, e) {
// -----------------------^
    if (ctrl.user.has.something) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    } else {
        ctrl.openMenu(m, e);
        // -----------^
    }
};
```